# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" in really basic code

Tags: javascript, html

I just created a really basic html file with js script included:

**JS file:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  alert("asdas");
</script>
```

**HTML file:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And I have no idea why it doesn't work. I'm dealing with it for 2 days. I've never had a problem like that with my html/js websites. The error appears on Chrome's JS console, but the code also doesn't work on other browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a `.js` file you do not need the `<script>` tags.

Just use the plain code as

```
alert("asdas");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove script tag from .js file.